WebView: the order of execution of jsBridge and MouseEvent handler
I am working with JavaFX WebView and need to do two things with it:
i) to call Java method from JS code on mouse click. For this I do
Java: 
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("myBridge", myBridge);
    }
});

JS: 
<div onclick="myBridge.foo()">    

So, in JS when a user clicks the div then myBridge.foo() is called .
ii) to call my handler on MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED for webView.
webView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
    //my handler code
});

My question - what will be called first - the java method of the bridge or MOUSE_CLICKED event handler.
Tests show that the method of the bridge is called first and after that event handler. But I need to know exactly, because I don't know how JS code is processed in WebView and what threads are used for that.

The documentation says "WebEngine objects must be created and accessed solely from the JavaFX Application thread. This rule also applies to any DOM and JavaScript objects obtained from the WebEngine object." which implies that the callbacks to the bridge object are invoked on the JavaFX Application Thread. I think it is safe to assume that. The order in which these happen is not specified, and generally orders of event notification in JavaFX are not fully specified (there are some exceptions). So if you need to process these in a particular order you need to code defensively to do so.

Event Delivery
The events probably follow the "Event Delivery Process".
So:

In the capture phase, a Java event filter on WebView could catch the event.
Then it would be routed to the WebView, where a JavaScript event filter or event handler could process the event.
Finally in the bubbling phase, (if the event wasn't already consumed), the event would be routed to a Java event handler on the WebView.

I only say probably because I didn't test it and things are complicated by mixing JavaFX and WebEngine tech, so something unexpected could happen. However, I would be reasonably confident that the steps above define the order of event processing for a WebView.
Threading
If you are concerned about threading, and wish to code defensively as suggested by James in comments, once you receive a callback from JavaScript, you could wrap any code in:
if (!isFxApplicationThread()) { 
     Platform.runLater(() -> /** your code **/); 
} else {
     /** your code **/
}

to ensure that your code is executed on the correct thread.
The Oracle tutorial for JavaFX/JavaScript integration does not check threads nor mention that it is necessary, so it is probably not necessary.

I ran a quick test of this, and it looks like (on my system) the Javascript callback occurs even before an event filter on the WebView. (All on the FX Application Thread.)
